# Mixpanel returning a response object instead of undefined even when opted out in AVA Unit Test

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I'm trying to implement an AVA Unit Test for my mixpanel implementation. To do this, I'm comparing the result of mixpanel.track() where if it returns anything, the track was successful, otherwise, it should be undefined.

I thought maybe it was that it was using a different mixpanel instance so I tried creating a named instance and ensuring that but it was to no avail. I'm also trying the same process but with Amplitude and it seems to be working fine (when I am opted out, the response fails as expected)

I have done this in my components where if
`const test = mixpanel.track('event_name', {})` is successful, !!test === true but if I do `mixpanel.opt_out.tracking()` prior to `const test = mixpanel.track('event_name', {})`, then !!test === undefined.

Expected behaviour (and the observed behaviour when I use it in my components):

```
trackResponse === undefined
```

Observed behaviour:

```
trackResponse === { event: 'asdf',
  properties:
   { '$browser': 'Safari',
     '$current_url': 'about:blank',
     '$browser_version': null,
     '$screen_height': 0,
     '$screen_width': 0,
     mp_lib: 'web',
     '$lib_version': '2.30.1',
     time: 1572898982.142,
     distinct_id: '[some_id]',
     '$device_id': '[some_id]',
     '$initial_referrer': '$direct',
     '$initial_referring_domain': '$direct',
     token: '[token]' } }
```

where [some_id] and [token] are some distinct values I've deleted.

I don't understand why in the AVA test, I'm receiving a response when normally a failed `track()` results in an undefined response. Could someone shine some light on this?

Let me know if I need to provide any additional information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in case anyone else runs into this issue.

I used a debugger to step into the `mixpanel.track()` calls and figured out that to see if the user had opted out, mixpanel checks for a property in the `localStorage` and compares it to see if it's `=== to '0'`. If this fails, it assumes the user has not opted out and carries out the `track` call as normal.

I guess during the AVA test, it was unable to access this property and assumed the user had not opted out. To fix it, in my call to `mixpanel.init()`, I added `opt_out_tracking_persistence_type: 'cookie'` as an option so that my `opt_out` call was being saved somewhere that the property could be accessed during the test.